# resposta de colisão entre circulos não está funcionando em javascript

Tags: javascript, física

eu estou tentando implementar as equações pra resposta da colisão de dois círculos em um programa meu, mas todas elas ou deixavam a velocidade das bolas incrivelmente alta ou só funciona 50% das vezes (nas outras 50 as bolas só queriam ir mais na direção uma da outra ao invés de colidir)
alguém pode falar o que está errado ou simplesmente passar uma implementação das equações para eu adaptar ao meu programa?

o código que estou usando (o que funciona 50% das vezes):

```js
var v1 = Math.hypot(vx1, vy1);
var v2 = Math.hypot(vx2, vy2);
var theta1 = v1 === 0 ? 0 : vy1 >= 0 ? Math.acos(vx1 / v1) : 3 * Math.PI / 2 + Math.asin(vx1 / v1);
var theta2 = v2 === 0 ? 0 : vy2 >= 0 ? Math.acos(vx2 / v2) : 3 * Math.PI / 2 + Math.asin(vx2 / v2);
var phi = y1 - y2 >= 0 ? Math.acos((x1 - x2) / v2) : 3 * Math.PI / 2 + Math.asin((x1 - x2) / v2);
var termo1 = (v1 * Math.cos(theta1 - phi) * (m1 - m2) + 2 * m2 * v2 * Math.cos(theta2 - phi)) / (m1 + m2);
proximo_vx1 = termo1 * Math.cos(phi) + v1 * Math.sin(theta1 - phi) * Math.cos(phi + Math.PI / 2);
proximo_vy1 = termo1 * Math.sin(phi) + v1 * Math.sin(theta1 - phi) * Math.sin(phi + Math.PI / 2);
```

a primeira equação é a que usada acima (50% das vezes), a segunda equação é a que acelera as bolas demais

screenshot da Wikipédia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision, seção sobre colisões entre criculos):
[image]

Comment: Por favor reduza sua dúvida a uma questão de código JavaScript. Por exemplo, por que determinada expressão (mais simples que essas que você perguntou) que deveria resultar em determinado valor está dando outro valor que não era esperado. Provavelmente já vai ter resposta aqui no site.

Answer (score -1):

Bom, primeiro alguns cuidados devem ser tomados:

Suponha que um círculo possua uma velocidade em x muito superior a em y (ângulo pequeno) e que ambas as velocidades são positivas. Neste caso, é melhor fazer o arco seno (não o arco cosseno). Isso porque o cosseno deste ângulo muito pequeno é muito próximo de 1 (0.9999...) o que não é uma boa aproximação para ser utilizada, devido ao tipo de dado [Number](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp) ser do formato [Double](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). Já o seno deste ângulo é uma boa aproximação para ele. Portanto, fazer o arco seno é uma melhor aproximação do ângulo verdadeiro do que o arco cosseno.

Outro cuidado é o quadrante em que este ângulo está. Pois `cos(x) = cos(-x)` e `sin(π/2 + x) = sin(π/2 - x)`. Ou seja, dois ângulos podem gerar o mesmo valor de seno/cosseno. O método `Math.asin()` ([fonte](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/asin)) retorna um valor entre -π/2 e π/2. Já o método `Math.acos()` ([fonte](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/acos)) retorna entre 0 e π.

Se você quiser, você pode seguir com estes cuidados. Mas, para seu caso, existe uma forma mais fácil de lidar com eles: utilize o método `Math.atan2()` ([fonte](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2)). Neste método você entra com dois valores (dos dois catetos), ao invés do valor da tangente do ângulo (como é o método `Math.atan()`), e ele te retorna o ângulo entre -π e π.

```
var theta1 = atan2(vy1, vx1);
var theta2 = atan2(vy2, vx2);
```

Usei a [referência](https://williamecraver.wixsite.com/elastic-equations) indicada pela Wikipedia para encontrar o valor de φ:

```
var phi = Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1);
```

Por fim, é só fazer os cálculos das velocidades finais como indicado:
[image: Cálculo das velocidades finais]

**Observação**: Do [site](https://williamecraver.wixsite.com/elastic-equations) que é referência para a Wikipedia, se θ2 for o indicado pela imagem:
[image: Colisão de dois círculos, observação quanto ao θ2]

então de fato o seu valor é:

```
var theta2 = Math.PI - atan2(vy2, vx2);
```

---

Quando você diz:

> as bolas só queriam ir mais na direção uma da outra ao invés de colidir

você quer dizer que uma atravessa a outra?

Se for isso, você deve comparar a distância entre os centros dos círculos. Se for menor que a soma de seus raios, então está atravessando. Se não, então ainda não colidiu.

```
if(Math.hypot(x2-x1, y2-y1) <= raio1 + raio2){
    // colidiu
}
```

Comment: obrigado pela compreensão, e pelo que eu entendi e implementei, os cálculos dos ângulos estavam corretos (eu gosto de fazer as formulas eu mesmo, então foi o equivalente a atan2), e eu acho que não é pelo teste de colisão que elas atravessam uma a outra (tanto que eu já faço esse teste, só não mostrei ali para não dar muita poluição visual), eu acho que identifica a colisão mas as velocidades por algum motivo são calculadas de um jeito errado, mas é só o que eu acho.

se você quiser eu posso mostrar mais código, é só pedir

Comment: Entendo que você goste de gerar suas próprias fórmulas, mas, ainda assim, recomendo utilizar o atan2 para gerar e propagar menos erros. Podem ser vários fatores: experimente reduzir a magnitude da velocidade das bolas e ver se o problema continua. Após entrar em colisão, ele calcula apenas uma vez as novas velocidades ou continua calculando enquanto está na área de colisão? (Máquina de Estados: antes da colisão -> durante colisão (calcula apenas uma vez novas velocidades) -> pós colisão (saiu da área de colisão))

Comment: utilizei atan2 e não deu diferença visual, então não deve ser isso, mas vou manter atan2, quanto à velocidade das bolas, está baixa, e após entrar em colisão ele continua calculando enquanto está na área de colisão

Comment: Bom. Então é isso! Você tem de calcular apenas uma vez... Se continuar calculando é como se estivesse colidindo mais de uma vez. Use uma `flag`: Se estiver na área de colisão && esta `flag` for `true`, Então calcule novas velocidades e mude a `flag` para `false`. Depois só retorne-a para `true` quando estiver fora da área de colisão. Assim, a nova velocidade só será calculada uma vez.